# How can I get glibc as a static library?

Tags: compiling, glibc, static-linking

I want to compile a program and statically link it to glibc, so it can run on other Linux distributions without the user having to do any special configuration.

I tried using `CFLAGS="-static -static-libgcc"`, but it statically links against all other libraries required, except glibc. I tried searching the apt repositories for a static version of glibc, but I couldn't find any.

How can I get a static library version of glibc on Ubuntu 18.04?

More information:

- The project is using autotools
- I am using the default gcc preinstalled with Ubuntu
- I set CFLAGS with `export CFLAGS="-static -static-libgcc"`
- I am compiling the project with `cd tsschecker && ./autogen.sh && make`
- [Link to project](https://github.com/s0uthwest/tsschecker)(if you want to clone the project, make sure to use `git clone --recurse-submodules`)

Comment: Are you invoking `gcc` directly, as both compiler an linker? or via `make`? How are you passing the `CFLAGS` variable?

Comment: @steeldriver I added more information